# How to get records which has more than one entries on another table

Tags: sql-server

An example scenario for my question would be:

> How to get all persons who has multiple address types?

Now here's my sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_1 (
    ID uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY
    , FirstName nvarchar(max)
    , LastName nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmp_2 (
    SeedID uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY
    , SomeIrrelevantCol nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmp_3 (
    KeyID uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY
    , ID uniqueidentifier REFERENCES #tmp_1(ID)
    , SeedID uniqueidentifier REFERENCES #tmp_2(SeedID)
    , SomeIrrelevantCol nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp_1
VALUES
('08781F73-A06B-4316-B6A5-802ED58E54BE', 'AAAAAAA', 'aaaaaaa'),
('4EC71FCE-997C-46AA-B119-6C5A2545DDC2', 'BBBBBBB', 'bbbbbbb'),
('B0726ABF-738E-48BC-95CB-091C9D731A0E', 'CCCCCCC', 'ccccccc'),
('6C6CE284-A63C-49D2-B2CC-F25C9CBC8FB8', 'DDDDDDD', 'ddddddd')

INSERT INTO #tmp_2
VALUES
('4D10B4EC-C929-4D6B-8C94-11B680CF2221', 'Value1'),
('4C891FE9-60B6-41BE-A64B-11A9A8B58AB2', 'Value2'),
('6F6EFED6-8EA0-4F70-A63F-6A103D0A71BD', 'Value3')

INSERT INTO #tmp_3
VALUES
(NEWID(), '08781F73-A06B-4316-B6A5-802ED58E54BE', '4D10B4EC-C929-4D6B-8C94-11B680CF2221', 'sdfsdgdfbgcv'),
(NEWID(), '08781F73-A06B-4316-B6A5-802ED58E54BE', '4C891FE9-60B6-41BE-A64B-11A9A8B58AB2', 'asdfadsas'),
(NEWID(), '08781F73-A06B-4316-B6A5-802ED58E54BE', '4C891FE9-60B6-41BE-A64B-11A9A8B58AB2', 'xxxxxeeeeee'),
(NEWID(), '4EC71FCE-997C-46AA-B119-6C5A2545DDC2', '4D10B4EC-C929-4D6B-8C94-11B680CF2221', 'sdfsdfsd'),
(NEWID(), 'B0726ABF-738E-48BC-95CB-091C9D731A0E', '4D10B4EC-C929-4D6B-8C94-11B680CF2221', 'zxczxcz'),
(NEWID(), 'B0726ABF-738E-48BC-95CB-091C9D731A0E', '6F6EFED6-8EA0-4F70-A63F-6A103D0A71BD', 'eerwerwe'),
(NEWID(), '6C6CE284-A63C-49D2-B2CC-F25C9CBC8FB8', '4D10B4EC-C929-4D6B-8C94-11B680CF2221', 'vbcvbcvbcv')
```

Which gives you:

[image: Table Data]

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
    , Cnt -- not really needed. Just added for visual purposes
FROM #tmp_1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        xt.ID
        , COUNT(1) Cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT
            #tmp_3.ID
            , COUNT(1) as Cnt
        FROM #tmp_3
        GROUP BY ID, SeedID
    ) xt
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.Cnt > 1
```

Which gives:

```
ID                                      FirstName   LastName    Cnt
B0726ABF-738E-48BC-95CB-091C9D731A0E    CCCCCCC      ccccccc     2
08781F73-A06B-4316-B6A5-802ED58E54BE    AAAAAAA      aaaaaaa     2
```

Although this gives me the correct results, I'm afraid that this query is not the right way to do this performance-wise because of the inner queries. Any input is very much appreciated.

*NOTE:*

1. A person can have multiple address of the same address types.
2. "Person-Address" is not the exact use-case. This is just an example.
3. The `Cnt` column is not really needed in the result set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you have named your sample tables and data help little in understanding the problem.

I think you want all IDs which have 2 or more SomeIrrelevantCol values in the last table?
This can be done by:

```
select * from #tmp_1
where ID in
(
    select ID
    from #tmp_3
    group by ID
    having count(distinct SomeIrrelevantCol)>=2
)
```

Comment: Nope, `#tmp_3.SomeIrrelevantCol` is not what I needed. What I wanted is `#tmp_2.SeedID`

Comment: This actually worked changing `SomeIrrelevantCol` into `SeedID`.